# Recuperar dados do DB a partir de uma determinada data

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize-js

Estou criando uma api em node.js, utilizando express e Sequelize como ORM. Gostaria de saber, qual expressão devo utilizar para recuperar os dados do DB a partir de uma determinada data. Estou utilizando o date-fns para determinar qual data exata seria o início dessa semana e armazenando o valor em uma variável, chamada **thisWeek**, que retorna:

```
2019-12-29T03:00:00.000Z
```

Como utilizo essa variável - **thisWeek** - para retornar apenas os resultados no banco de dados a partir dessa data? Abaixo está o trecho de código que estou utilizando para recuperar os dados do DB.

```
const checkQtt = await Checkin.findAll({
      where: { student_id: id }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma solução que resolveu meu problema:

Utilizei os Operadores do Sequelize. Para isso, importei-o:

```
import { Op } from "sequelize";
```

E no trecho de código onde recupero os dados do db e armazeno na variável, utilizei a seguinte expressão **- [Op.gt] -**, na qual me retorna apenas as linhas no qual o created_at sejam superiores à data da minha variável **thisWeek**:

```
const checkQtt = await Checkin.findAll({
      where: {
        student_id: id,
        created_at: {
          [Op.gt]: thisWeek
        }
      }
    });
```

Qualquer dúvida sobre trabalhar com os operadores no Sequelize, podem ser sanadas a partir da documentação: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html